# Parsing Fidelity Stock Quote page

Tags: excel, vba, stockquotes, msxml6

I have been able to obtain stock and index data from Fidelity by setting up a connection to the relevant Fidelity page; writing the results to a worksheet; and then finding the results I want on that sheet.

I am now trying to simplify and **avoid using both IE and the temporary worksheet page**.  The code below, using Microsoft XML, v6.0 seems to download all the relevant information, but I cannot figure out how to process things afterward so as to be able to extract the ***Name***, ***Last Price***, and ***Date/Time*** of that last price.

I have looked at Yahoo finance and Google finance, but they don't have all of the indices that I am interested in.

The code below gets me to the point of downloading the page information, but the only components that I see being returned by the "Get" is `responseText` (which I have split up and placed on a worksheet for examination), and `responseBody` which seems to be an array of character codes of the contents of `responseText`.

Perhaps I shouldn't even be using the MS XML tool in the first place, but it seems to me this should be possible.

Thanks for any pointers.

---

```
Sub FIDOQuoteTester()

'Set Reference to Microsoft XML V6.0

Const sURLPart1 As String = "http://quotes.fidelity.com/webxpress/get_quote?QUOTE_TYPE=D&SID_VALUE_ID="
Const sURLPart3 As String = "&submit=Quote"
Dim sURL As String
Dim sSymbols  As String '+ separated list
Dim REQ As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 'using Server type as the other raises security problems

Dim V As Variant, R As Range

Dim S As String

sSymbols = ".DJI+.SPX"
sURL = sURLPart1 & sSymbols & sURLPart3

Set REQ = New ServerXMLHTTP60
REQ.Open "Get", sURL, False
REQ.send

S = REQ.responseText

Stop

'putting string on worksheet for examination
'Need to split the string as it is too long for a cell.
V = Split(S, vbLf)
Set R = Range("a1").Resize(UBound(V) + 1, 1)
With R
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(V)
End With


End Sub
```

---

Comment: You can load the reposneText (in this case HTML) to the HTML object (mshtml.tlb) and then try parsing the td/tr elements.

Comment: @cyboashu I have not been able to figure out how to get that text into the HTML document object, in VBA.

Comment: see if the code (in answers) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a refernce to Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Then :

```
'/ Adding response text to  MSHTML

Dim oHTML       As New HTMLDocument
Dim e           '/ This is your element

oHTML.body.innerHTML = ""

oHTML.body.innerHTML = S '/ Set your responseText(HTML) here

'/ Loop through all the elements
For Each e In oHTML.all
    Debug.Print e.ID & "-->" & e.innerText
Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does it.   I guess I didn't realize that .innerHTML was read/write and not read-only.